# How can I get constant from formula at Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I added a trendline and get its linear equation value as `y = ax + b` form. In excel VBA how can I get constant `a` from this formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In formulas**

The following equations assume that your sheet has two named ranges: `x` and `y`. Then:

```
a = SLOPE(y,x)
b = INTERCEPT(y,x)
```

Source: [Chart Trendline Formulas](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/chart_trendline_formulas/)

Without named ranges, you use for example:

```vb
a = SLOPE(B2:B22, A2:A22)
b = INTERCEPT(B2:B22, A2:A22)
```

**In VBA**

```vb
rangeX = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(22, 1))) ' OR:  rangeX = Range("A2:A22")
rangeY = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(22, 2))) ' OR:  rangeY = Range("B2:B22")
a = Application.WorksheetFunction.Slope(rangeY, rangeX)
b = Application.WorksheetFunction.Intercept(rangeY, rangeX)
```

Comment: @Hakan – If it works for you, accept the most helpful answer by clicking check mark on the left.  Quality answers can be also upvoted.

Comment: Hi @miroxlav i voted yours because it seems ok but i have difficulties it to write on cell that constant 'a' also can't print on immediate windows debug.print

Comment: @Hakan – it seems you are mixing code from two answers together. Do you think you can use only the code from this answer? It is more difficult to understand the error when the code is mixed.

Answer (score 2):

you can read the actual formula by turning on the label

then read the label itself and parse it

```
Sub readFormula()

    Dim ttt As Trendline
    Set ttt = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1)

    ttt.DisplayEquation = True

    Debug.Print ttt.DataLabel.Caption
    Debug.Print ttt.DataLabel.Formula
    Debug.Print ttt.DataLabel.FormulaLocal
    Debug.Print ttt.DataLabel.FormulaR1C1
    Debug.Print ttt.DataLabel.FormulaR1C1Local
    Debug.Print ttt.DataLabel.Text

    ttt.DisplayEquation = False
end sub
```