# How to determine if the trendline is going up or down

Tags: excel, vba, equation, trendline

I have a dataset in sheet Data ("A1:B1000"). In column A a Date and in column B an integer.
Further more a PivotTable in sheet PT and a chart with a lineair trendline in sheet Dashboard.
I am able to get the formula from the trendline which looks like this:
y = 4,1793x + 101,42R² = 0,5576

What I would like to know is, if and how I can determine wether the trendline is going up or down.
I have been doing some research here and found this one f.i.:
[How can I get constant from formula at Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394389/how-can-i-get-constant-from-formula-at-excel-vba)

Any guidance how to approach this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking about a linear trendline: A positive slope means the trendline is going up, a negative slope means trendline is going down.

So in a linear equation `y = m⋅x + c` the `m` is the slope.

So in `y = 4,1793x + 101,42` the `m` is `4,1793` it is positive so it is going up.

The formula `Slope()` should give you the same result `4,1793` if you use it on the same data as your chart. So you just check if the result of the slope formula is positive or negative.

Comment: @MarcelEggen Of course, it's mathematics no magic here.